Is this a correct interpretation of what computeIfAbsent is doing in this code?
I am reading someone else's code which uses computeIfAbsent. I don't often use lambdas, and I want to be cautious as I try to understand what it's doing. Rewriting this for my own understanding, is this the correct interpretation?
map.computeIfAbsent(info.getOwner(), k -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>()).add(info);

Object owner = info.getOwner();
     
if (map.get(owner) == null)
   map.put(owner, new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Info>(Arrays.asList(info)));

Am I missing out on any benefits to not use the lambda method in this case? The documentation talks about computeIfAbsent() being atomic, but add() is not being called until after computeIfAbsent() returns. If the insertion is to be atomic, wouldn't putIfAbsent() have been more appropriate?

You don't show the declaration of list, but presumably it's a Map and not a List? Please [edit] your question and clarify that.

@tgdavies Yes, this was an oversight on my part as I simplified the code for presentation. I have corrected this in the question.

Yes, you are missing out on benefits. You've also misinterpreted what the code does a slight bit; you missed that it ends in .add(). (EDIT: I missed it too).
The lambda is short, sweet, and efficient
The lambda does not create things unless it must, it is atomic, and it does what you want, which is a simple to describe operation that gets quite tricky without the lambdas:
Have a map that maps keys to any number of values.
The problem with using a Map<String, List<String>> is that you can't simply write map.get(key).add(newValue) because that might throw NullPointerException if you're adding a value for that key for the first time. That lambda construct does it all:

create a new list.. but only if needed.
Ensure if that list is created, it is associated with the key.
Add an entry to that list. If it was created, add it to that. If there was already a list associated with it, add it to that.

Why not putIfAbsent?
With putIfAbsent, if the thing is not absent, the code still runs. You're still making a new 1-entry array with info in it, still making a wrapper list that wraps that, still making a CopyOnWriteArrayList that copies that wrapped list, handing a reference to this COWList to putIfAbsent which...
tosses it in the bin immediately.
Also, putIfAbsent returns null if it does a thing and returns what was there if it does not which is bizarre but makes some sense in light of what put returns. Point is, you cannot just call add on what it returns, so, there's no way to use putIfAbsent to end up with a simple chain of method calls that always does what you want.
Why not just do the if thing?
Because it's not atomic. Not all lists are atomic, of course, but the second snippet cannot possibly be atomic. Even if that list reference (which, apparently, is a map, that's a really bad name for a map!) is synchronized, that code does not work: Another thread could sneak a value in there in between your .get call and your put call.
So what are these lambda things?
The second snippet is sort of fine, it covers what you want to do, which is: Check if owner is already in this map. If it is not, then I'd like to make a new COWList and associate that as value with owner. But if it is, do nothing.
However, it doesn't do so atomically. And you can't fix that without taking control of the process of atomicity yourself, e.g. with synchronized. This is [A] limiting, in that any attempt to write a complicated approach to multicore safety is never going to work, as it'd need to be repeated every time you try to interact with the map (e.g. something like ConcurrentMap is a lot more complex than this stuff, and [B] is even then quite a bit of code. This:
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Info> list;
synchronized (map) {
  list = map.get(owner);
  if (list == null) {
    map.put(owner, list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Info>(Arrays.asList(info)));
  }
}

Is a lot to write. You'd have to copy it every time.
What you really want to do is hand something to the map impl so that it can do all these things. But, you need to give it a recipe: If the map itself decides that the key is not currently associated with a thing therefore it is time to make that thing and make that the value associated with the key, you need to hand it the recipe to make the thing.
And that's what lambdas are. recipes.
Just like you can eat a cake, but you can't eat a cake recipe, a lambda is not the same thing as what it makes.
Just like you can cook a recipe 0 times, 1 time, or 100 times, you can invoke a lambda as often as you want. Which includes 'never' - which is what the computeIfAbsent code is going to do if the key is not absent.
Just like a recipe, it is easy to copy around (you can hand lambdas around, they are cheap to 'make', just like its a lot simpler to copy a recipe vs copying a cake).
Just like a recipe, it can have parameters. A recipe usually just says 'take your pan and heat it'. It generally does not include instructions as to how to craft a cooking pan together. Instead the recipe requires a pan as input. No pan? Can't 'invoke' the recipe.

@tgdavies I missed it. Answer updated, including a section on what this really does (which is: have a map that maps keys to a list of values).

I believe the add() adds the info to the new List to be added to the map. This should be covered by my call to the constructor for CopyOnWriteArrayList().

Rereading these answers and comments, it sounds like the detail I missed is that add() executes even if the map contains the key. The empty list is only added if there is no key present, otherwise add() is still called on the existing list. This is why computeIfAbsent() is used instead of putIfAbsent().

IMHO, more appropriate translation of the code would be list = map.get(owner);   if (list == null) {     map.put(owner, list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Info>());   }   list.add(info);.  @Zhro true, the actual detail missed in the question is that add executes on a list, which, if absent in the existing Map is computed and initialized against the key with the help of computeIfAbsent. By the way, this is clear in the default implementation of the API under the Map interface.


Rewriting this for my own understanding, is this the correct interpretation?

No, they are not the same.
First Case

The ArrayList will be created and added to the map if the value is not present. Then that list will be returned and info added.
If the value is present for that key, then the existing list will be returned and the info will be added.

Second Case

The ArrayList will only be added if the value is null. Then the new ArrayList will be added and the value added to that.
But no subsequent values will be added since map.get(owner) will not return null and the map.put will not execute.

Here is a demo of the results.
// first case
record Info(String getOwner) {}
Map<String, List<Info>> map = new HashMap<>();
Info info = new Info("Joe");
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(info.getOwner(),
            k -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>()).add(info);
}
System.out.println(map.get("Joe"));

// second case
map.clear();

String owner = info.getOwner();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (map.get("Joe") == null) {
        map.put(owner,
                new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Info>(Arrays.asList(info)));
    }
}
System.out.println(map.get("Joe"));}

prints
[Info[getOwner=Joe], Info[getOwner=Joe]]
[Info[getOwner=Joe]]

Notice the second case only contains one instance in the ArrayList.

The equivalent to your one liner map.computeIfAbsent(info.getOwner(), k -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>()).add(info); is equivalent to this:
Object owner = info.getOwner();
List<Info> list = map.get(owner);
if (list == null)
   map.put(owner, list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>());
list.add(info);

If you called it more than once with difference instances of the info with same value of getOwner then add must be called twice. Using new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(info)) won't work on second call (see WLS answer).
However the above expanded code is not thread-safe. Two callers could instantiate new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>() and they both add to their own lists, whereas the one-liner guarantees one instance of CopyOnWriteArrayList is used for the same owner, and CopyOnWriteArrayList.add() is called once per invocation and safely records each value.
